# Chrome extension icon per tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a small extension for chrome that acts as a toggle switch which runs a script on click and when clicked again kills that script by running an opposite one. When active the icon switches but the script works on a per tab basis yet the icon stays the same on all tabs.

So is there a way to have the icon change on each tab?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but there's obviously a way to do it, because AdBlock Plus changes its icon depending on whether the page in that tab has it enabled or not.

Comment: @Barmar yeah that's why I was interested because I see them do it but was unable to find anything on Google and it seems to be done per url and not tab basis anyway.

Comment: Simply specify `tabId: ` parameter [as documented](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon) and shown in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @wOxxOm I'm attempting to do this now